# When exactly does data.table preserve column names?

Tags: r, data.table

Some J expressions preserve column names, and some don't:

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(hello = 1)
d[, .(hello)]
#    hello
# 1:     1
d[, c(.(hello))]
#    V1
# 1:  1
d[, {.(hello)}]
#    hello
# 1:     1
d[, {1; .(hello)}]
#    V1
# 1:  1
d[, .(get("hello"))]
#    V1
# 1:  1
d[, mget("hello")]
#    hello
# 1:     1
d[, c(mget("hello"))]
# Error: value for ‘hello’ not found  # WTF?
d[, {1; mget("hello")}]
#    hello
# 1:     1
```

What's the general rule?

Comment: I think you meant "deduce" instead of "preserve", and the answer is always when it's easy, and sometimes when it's hard.

Comment: This `d[, c(mget("hello"))]` doesn't work, but this `d[, list(mget("hello"))]` does.

Answer (score 8):

This really isn't very mysterious. First note that `.` is a shorthand for `list` in `data.table`. With that in mind, this is what's happening.

Every single expression you have produces an **unnamed** list or vector, except for `mget` which spits out a named list. This is why `mget` examples have named results. In all of the other examples `data.table` only deduces the name in very simple expressions, which are equivalent to `list(items)`. There are a few more cases where you'd get name deduction that would involve `.SD`, but generally speaking - if you didn't name it (as `mget` does) and it's more complicated than `list(items)`, then don't expect name deduction.

Comment: The question then seems to be what data.frame's idea of "very simple expressions that are equivalent to `list(items)`" is. Apparently, `{.(hello)}` is and `c(.(hello))` isn't. I don't know what the rule is.

Comment: `c(.(hello))`, which is same as `c(list(hello))` is not equivalent to `list(hello)`; again, there is no rule as such - it's whatever someone has bothered to implement, which is mostly just `list(hello)`. Anything else that does magic for you is a bonus. And if your question is motivated by determinism - name the columns.

Comment: My question is what exactly "someone has bothered to implement". That's what I mean by the "general rule".

Comment: `identical(c(list("hello")), list("hello"))` is `TRUE`, so they're certainly equivalent semantically. The difference evidently is related to syntax.

Comment: You're right, it so happens that for this particular input, the function `c` is same as identity. That's not true generally, and you shouldn't expect the computer to have such high-level understanding of expressions to figure it out. Whatever the answer to "this is the current list of deductions" is - there is no guarantee that it won't change/expand/contract in the future (which is why I don't care to look through the code to compile it for you - it's there for you to look). The only thing you can expect to stay is `list(...)`. For everything else, if you want certainty - name your columns.

Comment: @Kodiologist If they are not provided, data.table has to deduce the names before evaluation and `identical(quote(c(list("hello"))), quote(list("hello")))` is not `TRUE`. After a cursory glance at the source, I believe data.table actually checks whether the j-expression is a call to list. If you wrap it in `c` it becomes a call to `c`.

Comment: @Roland That sounds like it could be the basis of a complete answer, if you'd like to try again.

Comment: @Kodiologist In contrast to me, eddi is a contributor to data.table. So, I'll leave this to him.

Comment: Look, `identical(quote({list("hello")}), quote(list("hello")))` is `FALSE`, yet `{.(hello)}` will deduce the name, while `{{.(hello)}}` won't. Maybe in the future it will, maybe it won't. And maybe in the future `{.(hello)}` will stop deducing as well and will strictly limit to `list`/`.`. Repeating myself for the umpteenth time - I only see this mattering if you're worried about uncertainty, and there is a solution for that. Outside of that I don't see the value of this question.

Comment: @eddi I can totally understand why you don't care about the question, although in that case, I think posting an answer was a weird choice. Rep-farming has its place, I guess.

Comment: I answered the part of the question that imo has value (and I'm referring to the part that I consider value-less in the above comment). You seem to be hurt that others don't necessarily share your values, but that's life. Note also, that at no point did you try to convince me that the portion of the question we're discussing here is actually worth answering/has value.