# Is there some way to keep variable names from.SD+.SDcols together with non .SD variable names in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Given a `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), v=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), y=c(1,3,6), a=1:9, b=9:1)
DT
   x v y a b
1: b 1 1 1 9
2: b 1 3 2 8
3: b 1 6 3 7
4: a 2 1 4 6
5: a 2 3 5 5
6: a 1 6 6 4
7: c 1 1 7 3
8: c 2 3 8 2
9: c 2 6 9 1
```

if one does

```r
DT[, .(a, .SD), .SDcols=x:y]
   a .SD.x .SD.v .SD.y
1: 1     b     1     1
2: 2     b     1     3
3: 3     b     1     6
4: 4     a     2     1
5: 5     a     2     3
6: 6     a     1     6
7: 7     c     1     1
8: 8     c     2     3
9: 9     c     2     6
```

the variables from `.SDcols` become prefixed by `.SD`. On the other hand, if one tries, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62282856/997979,

```r
DT[, c(.(a), .SD), .SDcols=x:y]
   V1 x v y
1:  1 b 1 1
2:  2 b 1 3
3:  3 b 1 6
4:  4 a 2 1
5:  5 a 2 3
6:  6 a 1 6
7:  7 c 1 1
8:  8 c 2 3
9:  9 c 2 6
```

the other variable name (`a`) become lost. (It is due to this reason that I re-ask the question which I initially marked as a duplicate to that linked above).

Is there some way to keep the names from both `.SD` variables and non `.SD` variables?

The goal is simultaneously being able to use `.()` to select variables without quotes and being able to select variables through `.SDcols = patterns("...")`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a _named list_ for "a": `DT[, c(.(a = a), .SD), .SDcols=x:y]` (as in the post you linked to), or using `mget`: `DT[, c(mget("a"), .SD), .SDcols=x:y]` (as in a related post: [When exactly does data.table preserve column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53745905/when-exactly-does-data-table-preserve-column-names)) Related issue: [Document when exactly the column names from `j` are preserved](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3244); "for now, _just use a named list_... there's also something to be said for the
readability of explicit naming..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not really sure why.. but it works ;-)

```
DT[, .(a, (.SD)), .SDcols=x:y]
#    a x v y
# 1: 1 b 1 1
# 2: 2 b 1 3
# 3: 3 b 1 6
# 4: 4 a 2 1
# 5: 5 a 2 3
# 6: 6 a 1 6
# 7: 7 c 1 1
# 8: 8 c 2 3
# 9: 9 c 2 6
```

Comment: More correct is to use name for a column: DT[, c(.(a=a), .SD), .SDcols=x:y]. .SD is a list so combining with new list element 'a' should be made using c().

Comment: @jangorecki Thanks for comment. My question is due to that I have a lot of variables beyond `a`, so I wanted to know how to avoid naming each of them `c(.SD, .(a=a,a1=a1,a2=a2,a3=a3,...))`. I saw that also works `DT[, .(a, as.vector(.SD)), .SDcols=x:y]`, but using `as.vector` may not be an improvement since "the details of most coercions are undocumented and subject to change." and it's actually changing on R-devel. (I've just read: "‘as.vector’ got a ‘data.frame’ method which now returns a simple list (also obeying a long standing ‘FIXME’ to enable ‘as.vector(<data.frame>, mode="list")’. ")

Comment: Currently (R 4.2.3) the `as.vector` version does not work, but answer version works nicely yet.